# Ping from OpenVZ host to container

Tags: iptables, openvz

I have a host with multiple containers. I would to ping from the host to  container, and vice versa. Currently ping works only from inside a container to the host, e.g.:

```
root@c1313s02:~# vzctl enter 112 
entered into CT 112
root@orbit:/# ping 192.168.1.21
PING 192.168.1.21 (192.168.1.21) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.21: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.036 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.21: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.21: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.21 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.036/0.037/0.039/0.005 ms
root@orbit:/# exit
logout
exited from CT 112
```

Trying to ping from the host to the container does not work:

```
root@c1313s02:~# ping -c 3 192.168.1.13 
PING 192.168.1.13 (192.168.1.13) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.1.13 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
```

Sometime the IPTables log will show:

```
Mar 25 11:11:13 c1313s02 kernel: IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=192.168.1.13 DST=192.168.1.21 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=1977 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=0 CODE=0 ID=64315 SEQ=18
```

How can I update my IPTables rules to allow ping from the Host to the container?

Comment: We can't guess what iptables rules already exist on your rig, post them for relevant tables (`iptables -nvL -t <nat|filter>`).

Comment: @XavierLucas, I found the solution after carefully reading what my IPTables is doing

Answer (score 0):

I found out the the proxmox server create a device called `venet0`. So now my IPtables look like this:

```
...
$IPT -P INPUT DROP
$IPT -P OUTPUT DROP
...
$IPT -A INPUT -i venet0
```

Now I can ping from the container to the VZ hosts and vice versa.